# Count of most 'two words combination' popular Hebrew words in a pandas Dataframe with nltk

Tags: python, pandas, utf-8, nltk, hebrew

I have a csv data file containing column 'notes' with satisfaction answers in Hebrew.

I want to find the most popular words and popular '2 words combination', the number of times they show up and plotting them in a bar chart.

My code so far:

```
PYTHONIOENCODING="UTF-8"  
df= pd.read_csv('keep.csv', encoding='utf-8' , usecols=['notes'])
words= df.notes.str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts()
```

This produce a list of the words with a counter but takes into account all the stopwords in Hebrew and don't produce '2 words combination' frequencies.
I also tried this code and it's not what I'm looking for:

```
 top_N = 30
 txt = df.notes.str.lower().str.replace(r'\|', ' ').str.cat(sep=' ')
 words = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(txt)
 word_dist = nltk.FreqDist(words)
 rslt = pd.DataFrame(word_dist.most_common(top_N),
                columns=['Word', 'Frequency'])
 print(rslt)
 print('=' * 60)
```

How can I use nltk to do that?

Comment: how are you handling hebrew words prefix? הובכמ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`nltk.util.bigrams`](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html#nltk.util.bigrams):

Solution for count bigrams from all values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'notes':['aa bb cc','cc cc aa aa']})

top_N = 3
txt = df.notes.str.lower().str.replace(r'\|', ' ').str.cat(sep=' ')
words = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(txt)

bigrm = list(nltk.bigrams(words))
print (bigrm)
[('aa', 'bb'), ('bb', 'cc'), ('cc', 'cc'), ('cc', 'cc'), ('cc', 'aa'), ('aa', 'aa')]

word_dist = nltk.FreqDist([' '.join(x) for x in bigrm])
rslt = pd.DataFrame(word_dist.most_common(top_N),
                columns=['Word', 'Frequency'])
print(rslt)
    Word  Frequency
0  cc cc          2
1  aa bb          1
2  bb cc          1
```

Solution for bigrams per each splitted value of column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'notes':['aa bb cc','cc cc aa aa']})

top_N = 3
f = lambda x: list(nltk.bigrams(nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(x)))
b = df.notes.str.lower().str.replace(r'\|', ' ').apply(f)
print (b)

word_dist = nltk.FreqDist([' '.join(y) for x in b for y in x])
rslt = pd.DataFrame(word_dist.most_common(top_N),
                    columns=['Word', 'Frequency'])
print(rslt)
    Word  Frequency
0  aa bb          1
1  bb cc          1
2  cc cc          1
```

If need count bigrams with separate words:

```
top_N = 3
f = lambda x: list(nltk.everygrams(nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(x, 1, 2)))
b = df.notes.str.lower().str.replace(r'\|', ' ').apply(f)
print (b)

word_dist = nltk.FreqDist([' '.join(y) for x in b for y in x])
rslt = pd.DataFrame(word_dist.most_common(top_N),
                    columns=['Word', 'Frequency'])
```

and last plot by [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
rslt.plot.bar(x='Word', y='Frequency')
```

Comment: The first solution worked "Solution for count bigrams from all values"- How can I export to csv file so the words won't be in gibberish?
The second & third solutions didn't work. I received an error- "expected string or bytes-like object"

Comment: @Liron - You can change `word_dist = nltk.FreqDist(bigrm)` to `word_dist = nltk.FreqDist([' '.join(x) for x in bigrm])`  for strings and last for file use `rslt.to_csv('file_out.csv', index=False)`

Comment: Also, I wanted to make sure that all the combinations I'm receiving from the first solution are indeed from the same sentence, right? and not from all the list.

Comment: @Liron - it means like `aa bb cc` in sample data is always one `sentence`, or possible multiple one? Is possible change `df = pd.DataFrame({'notes':['aa bb cc','cc cc aa aa']})` similar like in your real data?

Comment: `rslt.to_csv('file_out.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')`- that what I wrote but the words still in gibberish

Comment: @Liron - file is confidental?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197443/discussion-between-liron-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what jezrael posted, I would like to introduce another hack of achieving this. Since you are trying to get individual as well as the two-word frequencies, you can also take advantage of the [everygram](https://tedboy.github.io/nlps/generated/generated/nltk.everygrams.html) function.

Given a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['notes'] = ['this is sentence one', 'is sentence two this one', 'sentence one was good']
```

Get the one-word and two-word forms using `everygrams(word_tokenize(x), 1, 2)`, to get the combinations of one, two, three word combinations, you can change 2 to 3, and so on. So in your case it should be:

```
from nltk import everygrams, word_tokenize

x = df['notes'].apply(lambda x: [' '.join(ng) for ng in everygrams(word_tokenize(x), 1, 2)]).to_frame()
```

At this point you should see:

```
                                               notes
0  [this, is, sentence, one, this is, is sentence...
1  [is, sentence, two, this, one, is sentence, se...
2  [sentence, one, was, good, sentence one, one w...
```

You can now get the count by flattening the list and value_counts:

```
import numpy as np

flattenList = pd.Series(np.concatenate(x.notes))
freqDf = flattenList.value_counts().sort_index().rename_axis('notes').reset_index(name = 'frequency')
```

Final output:

```
           notes  frequency
0           good          1
1             is          2
2    is sentence          2
3            one          3
4        one was          1
5       sentence          3
6   sentence one          2
7   sentence two          1
8           this          2
9        this is          1
10      this one          1
11           two          1
12      two this          1
13           was          1
14      was good          1
```

And now plotting the graph is easy:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

plt.figure()
flattenList.value_counts().plot(kind = 'bar', title = 'Count of 1-word and 2-word frequencies')
plt.xlabel('Words')
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]